# Select by location are within source layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, select-by-location

So I am trying to select all of the block groups inside a group of counties. So I am using the select by location tool and setting my target layer as the block group and my source layer as my counties. then I am using the are within the source layer feature.

I thought that was how you did that, but it seems that it is only selecting the ones that are completly within each county. Am i just wrong here? [image: an image of the process and result i am going through.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread has been latent for a while already, but I´m going to stir it a little, since I think there is more to be said on the subject than is stated here.

I´m using the same version ArcGIS and I could´nt get the Clementini-trick posted by [mapBaker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9880/mapbaker) to work on my system. I kept getting the same results as "intesects" (don´know why yet, mystery still to be resolved), but thats not what is asked for in the question. ArcGIS does however have a method for selecting called "have their centroid in the source layer", which should work in most cases of this particular task.

However, you could have a situation where the centroid of a block group falls outside the border of a county. In this case that particular block group won´t be selected and your selection will not be complete. When this is the case you´ll have to switch tools and hop on to QGIS, which has a solution for this problem. In [this](http://gisforthought.com/centroid-within-selection-in-qgis/) article by [Heikki Vesanto](http://gisforthought.com/aboutme/) you´ll find the workflow laid out. This functionality is nowadays available as a QGIS plugin, which makes the task even much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Contain (Clementini)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) method:

> This operator provides the same results as Contain unless the source
>   feature is entirely on the boundary of the target feature, with no
>   part of the source feature inside the target feature. In this case,
>   using the Contain Clementini operator does not select the target
>   feature, whereas the Contain operator does. Clementini states that a
>   polygon's boundary is separate from its inside and outside.

I use this method and it works well for what you're doing here.